# Conditional sql join query to get proper columns from each tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, Let say these;

```
Table1:id,type,text
Table2:id,table1_id,col1,col2
Table3:id,table1_id,colA,colB
```

So I want to write a sql like ;`select * from Table1 /*join here, dont know*/ where id =3`
to get conditional result, table1.* and table2.* or table.3 according to type..

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use an if statement in a stored procedure to select from the appropriate table, conditionally on the type. Something along the lines of

```
if type = something
    select from table2 ...
else
    select from table3 ...
end if
```

Comment: I mean I want to select table1 data and merge it with table2 or table3 by type

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 On Table2.table1_id = Table1.id WHERE Table1.id = 3
```

Comment: so where is the table3 and conditional join?